# Activate automatic hyphenation with GemBox Document

Tags: gembox-document

How can one activate the automatic hyphenation for created word documents?
In word, the option is under `Layout->Hyphenation`(Group "Page Setup"), however I was not able to find this setting in the document model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (2020-05-22)**

In the current latest version (GemBox.Document 3.1), there is API support for [AutoHyphenation](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/help/html/P_GemBox_Document_HyphenationOptions_AutoHyphenation.htm).
For example, try using this:

```cs
var document = DocumentModel.Load("Input.docx");
document.HyphenationOptions.AutoHyphenation = true;
```

**ORIGINAL**

In the current version (GemBox.Document 2.5) this is not supported through an API, it's supported only through preservation.

In other words, when loading a DOCX file, which has this option enabled, into a DocumentModel and then saving that DocumentModel into a DOCX file, the resulting output DOCX file will have that option enabled as well. But when changing the output file's format into something other than the input format (for example to PDF, XPS, HTML, etc.) then the preserved information is lost.

Last as a feedback reference can you specify exactly for what output file format do you require this?

Comment: Thanks for the information. As for your request, the output format is .docx. If this the hyphenation option would be in the default document model of a future release, we would be pleased.